# Como cambiar el valor NULL a un valor string

Tags: java, android-studio

Estimados soy nuevo en esto, estoy empezando a programar en Android Studio.
Tengo un inconveniente en donde en el campo de una tabla me viene con el valor NULL y no quiero que venga con ese valor, quiero que a pesar de que venga con ese valor me lo pase a '0'.

Como se podría realizar esa modificación en android?

public static EntregaFacturaRecord load(Cursor cursor){

```
    EntregaFacturaRecord record = new EntregaFacturaRecord();

    if( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {

        record.setIdEntrega( cursor.getString(0) );
        record.setOrdenFactura( cursor.getInt(1) );
        record.setIdEntregaFactura(cursor.getString(2));
        record.setIdFactura( cursor.getString(3) );
        record.setIdOpcionEntrega( cursor.getInt(4) );
        record.setCantItemsEntregaTotal( cursor.getInt(5) );
        record.setCantItemsEntregaParcial( cursor.getInt(6) );
        record.setCantItemsNoEntregados( cursor.getInt(7) );
        record.setObservaciones( cursor.getString(8) );
        record.setReasignar( cursor.getString(9) );
        record.setSincronizado( cursor.getInt(10) );
        record.setStatus( cursor.getInt(11) );
        record.setActivo( cursor.getString(12) );
        record.setIdMotivoNoEntrega(cursor.getString(13));
        record.setRecalculada(cursor.getString(14));
        record.setRecalculadaManual(cursor.getString(15));
        record.setId( cursor.getInt(16) );

        record.setLoaded(true);

    }

    return record;
}

public Cursor getByCondition(String condition) {
    Cursor mCursor =
            this.mDb.query(true,
                    DATABASE_TABLE,
                    columns, condition, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}
```

}##

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías crear una condición IF, en donde cuando el valor llegue nulo sea igual a 0:  
if(valor == null)
{ valor="0"; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pues hay varias maneras de controlar esto.
Una de ellas es (si tienes control de la base de datos) es agregar un valor por defecto en la tabla para el campo que necesitas:

```
-- (Sentencia de alteración en MySQL)
ALTER TABLE your-table-name
ALTER your-column-name SET DEFAULT your-default-value;
```

Otra forma es validando el valor que quieres recibir en el setter de tu clase EntregaFacturaRecord. Por ejemplo:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class EntregaFacturaRecord {
    // omito el resto de la configuración
    public void setOrdenFactura(Integer ordenFactura) {
        this.ordenFactura = Objects.nonNull(ordenFactura) ? ordenFactura : 0;
    }
}
```

También puedes crear una clase utilitaria (si sabes de genéricos) para que reciba tu valor desconocido, interprete el tipo de dato y retorne un valor por defecto. Un ejemplo sería:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public final class ObjectEval {
    private ObjectEval() {}
    
    public static Integer evalInteger(Integer value) {
        return Objects.nonNull(value) ? value : 0;
    }
}
```

Entonces, con esta clase utilitaria, lo que haces es interceptar las respuestas del resultset que usas, así:

```
record.setOrdenFactura( ObjectEval.evalInteger(cursor.getInt(1)) );
```

Esta opción es mas adecuada ya que no tienes que modificar los getters y setters de todos tus objectos modelos.

Pueden existir mejores alternativas que estas (como usar un patrón Builder en tu modelo)... ya tendrías que buscarlas por tu cuenta.